# Can I build a PyInstaller binary for M1 Macs on an Intel Mac?

Tags: pyinstaller

I have recently found out that PyInstaller now works on macOS Monterey, so I tried to build a binary. When testing on my Intel machine, it did work as expected. When testing it on an M1 MacBook, however, it failed to work because of "Damaged and cannot open". I think that was because of the incompatibility of Intel apps and M1 apps.
CLang has an option to build for a different architecture, but I don't know if PyInstaller has such parameter that does the same job.
[image: Proof]
Proof: From the picture, the app is clearly stated to be an "Intel" app.
Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Did you check https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues?

Comment: You should be getting universal builds, per https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/pull/5581.  Where did you get the code you're compiling?  Which branch?

Comment: did you follow steps proposed in these threads, if applicable (?): https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/5886
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/5315

Comment: Thanks everybody. I'll try follow these steps.

Comment: I found the switch finally! It's in https://readthedocs.org/projects/pyinstaller/downloads/pdf/stable/#page20  Where the control is actually --target-arch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a target architecture in the .spec file. I'm have the opposite problem... built on M1 and need to target both.... in the middle of solving the problem but it may be as simple as specifying the Architecture in the .spec file.